# refresh facebook access token after login using ionic with AWS Cognito Federated Identity and AWS amplify

Tags: ionic3, facebook-javascript-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have an hybrid application that uses Cognito Federted Identity (Facebook) to log in along side the Cognito User Pool using AWS Amplify Javascript library. 
The login with Cognito User Pool works fine, AWS amplify handle the token refreshing so the users are never logged out of the application even if the application is restarted. 
This is not the same using federated identity: after the login with Facebook I get a short-lived Access Token (1 hour) that I exchange with an AWS token using AWS.federatedSign().

AWS Amplify Official Documentation says that ASW amplify should automatically refresh the token for both google/facebook. In my case I receive the error:

```
refreshing federation token failed: no fb sdk available
```

Answer (score 0):

The AWS documentation is not great, my understanding (having just battled with this for a couple of days) is as below. Hopefully it helps...

There are two scenarios in which Amplify/Cognito supports federated authentication.

1) Where a Federated authentication provider is used to sign into a Cognito *User-Pool*.  This is (as best I can tell) only possible when using the Cognito hosted site to login. Your code might resemble...

```
Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: 'Facebook'})
```

or

```
Auth.federatedSignIn()
```

2) Where your application authenticates directly to Facebook (e.g. using the device native application), and then authenticates with a Cognito *Identity-Pool* using the facebook authToken. Your code might look something like...

```
fb.login(['public_profile', 'email'])
.then(response => {
  // Some object marshalling omitted...
  Auth.federatedSignIn('facebook', { token: accessToken, expires_at }, user)
})
```

The AWS Documentation frequently seems not to distinguish between the two very different use-cases, but in general scenario 1 is better/more-frequently documented.

In the first scenario Cognito does as you expect, i.e. manages the life-cycle expiry for both Cognito and Facebook tokens.  The down-side of this is you need to exit you application to conduct authentication which has some impact on user-experience particular for a device-native or hybrid-application.

In the second scenario - I believe that all Cognito does is provide you IAM credentials (of the specified role) in exchange for your Provider credentials.  You have to implement the token lifecycle for the provider token yourself in your application.

It doesn't directly answer your question, but I found this a very useful guide
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc_cognito.html

I've also create a blog detailing how I got this working in Ionic
https://martincroker.wordpress.com/2019/07/09/using-ionic-with-aws-amplify-facebook-authentication/